# How to calculate gap between 2 timestamps (edited for AWS Athena )

Tags: amazon-athena

I Have many IOT devices that sends data to my Amazon Athena server, i created a table to store the data and the table contains 2 columns: LocalTime indicate the time that the IOT device capture his status, ServerTime indicate the time the Data arrived to server (sometimes the IOT device doesn't have network connections )

I would like to count the "gaps" in block of hours (let's say 1 hour ) in order to know the deviation of the data arriving, for example:
[image]

the result that I would like to get is:

[image]

In order to calculate the result i want to calculate how many hours passed between  serverTime and LocalTime.
so the first entry (1.1.2019 12:15 - 1.1.2019 10:25 ) = 1-2 hours.

Thanks

Comment: Please tag your database name.

Comment: Which DB system are you using (MySQL, SSMS, etc)?

Comment: Yes, the date/time/timestamp functions differ a lot between different database engines. Please tell us which one you are using. Also, please indicate the specific **data type** the columns have.

Answer (score 0):

If it is **MSSQL Server** is your database, you can try this below script to get your desired output-

```
SELECT  
CAST(DATEDIFF(HH,localTime,serverTime)-1  AS VARCHAR) +'-'+
    CAST(DATEDIFF(HH,localTime,serverTime)  AS VARCHAR) [Hours],
COUNT(*) [Count]
FROM your_table
GROUP BY CAST(DATEDIFF(HH,localTime,serverTime)-1  AS VARCHAR) +'-'+
    CAST(DATEDIFF(HH,localTime,serverTime)  AS VARCHAR)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Oracle

If you using Oracle database as a system, you can use this statement:

```
select CONCAT(CONCAT (diff_hours,'-') , diff_hours+1) as Hours, count(diff_hours) as Count 
from (select 24 * (to_date(LocalTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi') - to_date(ServerTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi')) diff_hours from T_TIMETABLE ) 
group by diff_hours 
order by diff_hours;
```

*Note:* This will not display the empty intervals.